# Split non-uniform data

Tags: vba, excel

I have three pieces of data in a cell that I would like to separate. Right now my cells look something like this with all different positions, emails, and phone numbers:

[image]

I would like my data to look like this:

[image]

I am looking for any sort of Excel formula or VBA code to make this possible. I thought maybe some sort of combination of a MID, LEFT, RIGHT, and FIND would work, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Is there a delimiter between each piece of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. These are kind of long formulas, so best to copy and paste them.

Let's assume your data start in cell A2.

In cell B2, enter this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-3)),99),"")
```

In cell C2, enter this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-3))+1,99),MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-2)),99),"")
```

In cell D2, enter this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-2))+1,99),MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-1)),99),"")
```

In cell E2, enter this formula:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))-1))+1,99)
```

Now select the range B2:E2 and copy downward as far as you need.

That's it.

Comment: This works perfectly! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

VBA version (all text in column A)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub customSplit()
    Dim part1, part2, part3, cel As Range, v As Variant, i As Long

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = .Columns("A:E")
        For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If Len(v(i, 1)) > 0 Then
                part1 = InStr(v(i, 1), "@")
                If part1 > 0 Then
                    part2 = InStrRev(v(i, 1), " ", part1)
                    part3 = Split(Right(v(i, 1), Len(v(i, 1)) - part2))
                    If UBound(part3) = 3 Then
                        v(i, 2) = Left(v(i, 1), part2 - 1)
                        v(i, 3) = part3(0)
                        v(i, 4) = part3(1)
                        v(i, 5) = part3(2) & " " & part3(3)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        With .Columns("A:E")
            .Value = v
            .AutoFit
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Total Rows: 1,048,576; duration: 13.625 seconds

Sample result:

```
Associate Professor jane.doe@example.com 777-123-4567 GWC 123            Associate Professor            jane.doe@example.com   777-123-4567   GWC 123
Business Operation Specialist john.doe@example.com 777-456-7890 GWC 456  Business Operation Specialist  john.doe@example.com   777-456-7890   GWC 456
Associate Professor jane.doeexample.com 777-123-4567 GWC 124
Business Operation Specialist john.doe@example.com 777-456-7890 457
Associate Professor jane.doe@example.com 777-123-4567 GWC 125            Associate Professor            jane.doe@example.com   777-123-4567   GWC 125
Associate Professor jane.doe@example.com 777-123-4567 GWC 124            Associate Professor            jane.doe@example.com   777-123-4567   GWC 124
Business Operation Specialist john.doe@example.com 777-456-7890 GWC 457  Business Operation Specialist  john.doe@example.com   777-456-7890   GWC 457
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! It is throwing an error where you set part2 = InStrRev... saying "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: That error is thrown when source data doesn't contain an `@` sign (email address). I added validation to check source pattern for `word x N + " " + email + " " + phone + " " + word x 2`